# How to handle shadows in Three.js when using custom ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, shader, shadow

My question refers to newest version 80 of Three.js. 
I am using custom `ShaderMaterial` with lights and I want to incorporate shadows to the scene. I have followed [this](http://blog.edankwan.com/post/three-js-advanced-tips-shadow) tutorial by Edan Kwan.

Unfortunately in rev 80 there is no longer `ShaderChunk(shadowmap_fragment)` available. I noticed that there is separate ShadowMaterial created (src/materials/ShadowMaterial.js ) but I don't know how to use it with my shader material. Could anyone advise how to use it? Thank you.

Comment: I was trying to achieve the same thing. I found out that using the minified version of Three it wasn't working but the expanded one works with no problem. Not sure why.

Comment: UPDATE. I had to switch to r73 in order to have shadowmap_fragment back. Forget the above.